# Could not load file errors with Powerquery into Powerpivot ... not a programmer, but done this before without issue

Tags: excel, powerquery, 32bit-64bit, powerpivot, excel-2016

What I'm doing :

- 1.2M lines of data in two *.csv files located on my hard drive (represents receipt data since 1/1/19).   Columns are a mix of text and values
- Trying to use Power Query to load the two files into excel into the Data Model after transforming the data... delete columns, add columns (calculations).  Only way that I've been able to get this portion to work is to bring in as a pivot table when checking the "add to Data Model" box.  There are too many lines to add as a table or another worksheet and it doesn't work when I try to do the combo of 'connection only' and "add to data model".
- From the workbook that I ran the Power Query from, I was able to add information from a sheet into the Data Model as well by using the Data, Select from range, "add to Data model" path.
- When I attempt to go to Power Pivot to connect my transformed power query data with the data that I added into the Data Model, I get this error, "Could not load file or assembly, "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version 15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral... not enough memory" ... On previous attempts (when I was trying to use the 2 files as *.xlsm, I got ailed to connect to the server. Reason : could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 or one of its dependences. Not enough memory resources are available to process this command. (Exception HRESULT: ox80070008
- Running excel 2016 on Office 365.  32 bit.  Part of me wonders if this may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running into the 2 GB file size limit for Excel (32-bit).

> 32-bit environment is subject to 2 gigabytes (GB) of virtual address space, shared by Excel, the workbook, and add-ins that run in the same process. A data model’s share of the address space might run up to 500 – 700 megabytes (MB), but could be less if other data models and add-ins are loaded.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-model-specification-and-limits-19aa79f8-e6e8-45a8-9be2-b58778fd68ef)

---

You might be able to filter the rows or eliminate some columns to reduce the total amount of data.

Comment: I did filter out some "zero" spend invoice line items and that helped a bit, but I'm still getting some error messages when I try to use the "Manage" feature in Power Pivot.   Appreciate your advice and info!